# How to parse the XML which contains HTML contents

Tags: android

i am new for android. could you help me to parse this XML which contains the HTML contents like,

```
<title>Jeff Mayweather: Floyd Sr showed a Sign of finally letting go of his Son, Passing Torch to Roger</title>

<summary type="html">
                        &lt;p&gt;By Shawn Craddick&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Boxingsocialist had a chance to catch up with Floyd Mayweather&#039;s other uncle Jeff Mayweather. While Jeff stays busy at the gym he gave us some updates on his fighters as well as his thoughts on Brandon Rios, Gamboa, Floyd Mayweather Sr and Floyd Jr. meeting back together. Also he talked to us about a surprise boxing veteran he might be working with. Check out the interview below.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/br&gt; &lt;span style=&quot;color: #ff6600;&quot;&gt;BoxingSocialist&lt;/span&gt;- What did you…&lt;/p&gt;                    </summary>
```

I can parse the **title** field , For parsing the **summary** field I give the command in RSS handler-- **localname.equals("summary")**  . i cannot parse the content in the **summary** field. anyone help me on this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the html content in java.

tutorial [Link example](http://codeblow.com/questions/android-jsoup-parsing-tables-fromweb-sites/)

Cheers

Comment: I tried this. But this one too complicate.. anyway thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
android.text.Html.fromHtml(text).toString();
```

Comment: Won't help. Most parsers will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had such feed with html data inside tags. My solution was to ask data provider to wrap html with `CDATA`. So, if you have access to how xml is made, consider this option.